# VSTS Build warning: Could not find WindowsSDKDir error: Cannot open include file: 'windows.h'

Tags: visual-c++, azure-devops

I am trying to build a VC++ project through VSTS build server and it is failing with

Warning MSB8003: Could not find WindowsSDKDir variable from the registry.  TargetFrameworkVersion or PlatformToolset may be set to an invalid version number.

Error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'windows.h': No such file or directory

How ever Build Server has the WindowsSDKDir variable in the registry.
I have installed VS2012 ToolSet V110 on the build server.

It build fine in my local PC, and even in TFS (using XAML build definitions). We are migrating to VSTS and Trying to create build definition in VSTS.
This project is part of a big VS2017 solution which has many C# projects which build fine, but for this VC++ project which uses VS2012 toolset.

Build server has VS2017 installed.
The options I have
 - install windows SDK 
 - just install VS2012 (not ideal)

Comment: What's the result if you build the project manually on the build server?

Comment: I do not have admin/direct access on the server, I am working with operations team and through webinterface for builds.

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue with a new project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS 2017 can build with the `v141` (VS 2017) or `v140` (VS 2015) Platform Toolset. It does not support older toolsets such as `v120` (VS 2013) or `v110` (VS 2012).

> VS 2015 can build with `v140` (VS 2015) or `v120` (VS 2013) if you install the "Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.0/8.1 Tools". You'd have to go back to VS 2013 with the "Tools for Maintaining Store apps for Windows 8" component to get `v110` support.

Why not upgrade the VC++ project to use VS 2017 / v141?

Comment: Migrating to 2017 VC++ would be my last option, as with current configuration I can successfully build in my local and in TFS environment. What I am doing is to build it of VSTS build server so I can migrate to VSTS from TFS.